# Autonomous scripting

Tags: linux, bash, cron

How do I get a script to execute autonomously at 23:59 each day?

I figured using an `if` statement would work but how would I get a script that hasn't been executed yet to know when I want it to work?

If I were to run it first thing in the morning, is there some sort of entry I can use to keep the program alive until 23:59 where I can tell it to run it again at the given time?  That way it would only replace the file from earlier and give me a summarized report of the daily activity and I wouldn't have to write multiple scripts.

Comment: Check out `man crontab`

Comment: welcome to bash scripting! And I can't emphasis enough : have a look at *[BashPifFalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)* before one of those bite you! ^^ Bash is really good, but knowing about those will help tremendously (and will also help with other shells)

Answer (score 3):

> How do I get a script to execute autonomously at 23:59 each day?

[cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is the tool for the job.

You would have an entry that looks like

```
59 23 * * * /path/to/my_script.sh
```

Which means to run `/path/to/my_script` every day at 23:59.

Comment: Using CentOS, latest version..  does that mean that the entry should look like: crond 59 23 * * * [path]     ?

Comment: @user2212109: Check out the [CentOS guide to configuring cron tasks](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-autotasks-cron-configuring.html) for a little more info there.

Comment: If your script uses bash specifics, have the script start with, as the FIRST line : `#!/path/to/bash`  (see [SheBang on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) for a somewhat long explanation. In a nutshell it tell the shell to re-run using the /path/to/bash command. (usuallt /path/to/bash is /usr/bash or /usr/bin/bash : try `type -all bash` or `which bash` to find out the real path)